# Getting Runtime Error(NZEC) on SPOJ AND CODECHEF?? Couldn't find why this error is occuring on my code

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am getting RUNTIME ERROR(NZEC) on my following code while running my code on competetive programming sites.But could not understand where is the problem in my code as it is running absolutely fine on eclipse:

My code is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
        public boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
        String s1 = String.valueOf(number);
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(s1);
        String s2 = String.valueOf(s.reverse());
        if ((Integer.parseInt(s1)) == (Integer.parseInt(s2)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        int m1[] = new int[t];
       int k=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            int m = sc.nextInt();
            for (int j = m + 1;; j++) {
                Main main = new Main();
                if (main.isPalindrome(j)) {
                    m1[k++] = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int l=0;l<m1.length;l++)
        {
            System.out.println(m1[l]);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Did you submit this code on CodeChef/Spoj?

Your code seems to be fine but you should provide the input or run your code on an interactive console(as we do in terminal).
You can observe your error by commenting on the scanner lines and initializing the variables in the code itself as I checked this by running it on CodeChef

Else, Try adding this Scanner class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class
```

This error is caused when your code returns Non-Zero Error Code(NZEC)

Answer (score 0):

In languages which have exception handling like Java, Python etc we can use exception hadling using try - catch blocks.
NZEC is a runtime error.

for detailed answer to the above question

[click here](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/tutorial-how-to-debug-an-nzec-error/11221)

Comment: Can you provide an example / some code instead of just a link?